# Adobe Flash Player installation failed

Tags: install, error, adobe-flash

#### Background

When the Adobe Flash player update was auto-updated, I had to quit Safari and then continue the installation.
Accidentally, I started Safari again right during the installation procedure.

This resulted in a never-ending install that I had to force-quit.

So, I downloaded the [Uninstall Flash Player](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/909/cpsid_90906.html) software to completely remove flash from my system and then [re-install](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/) it.

#### Problem

The (new) install failes with the folloing error report:
[image]

How can I install flash now? How can this error occur even though Flash was apparently completely removed from the system?

Comment: Do you mean "How can I install Flash now" instead of "How can I install Safari now"?

Comment: Also, have you tried searching Spotlight for "flash" or "adobe" in case the uninstaller didn't take care of everything?

Comment: @bneely Thanks for the hint. Of course, I meant to ask "How can I install Flash now?". Searching in spotlight only shows some `font-adobe-blablabla` subdirectories which belong to macports. Then I've searched `~/Library` for flash and removed `com.adobe.blabla` folders and the Adobe Application support.

Comment: I've also searched `/Library` for 'flash' and 'adobe' without significant results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A restart fixed the problem. The installation worked without interruptions.